# Scrollable row of images

Tags: html, css, image, scrollbar

I have a small image that i need to repeat along the x direction, a specific number of times.
The 'row' of images should be scrollable, and i want to avoid tables if possible.

Is this possible to do with Html + Css? The html code will be dynamic generated using PHP.
Any extra-ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Use HTML5 and play around with canvas.

Comment: @David tags are html + css, no html5 or css3

Comment: @Bondye Ah, snap. Must've overlooked them.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if ajax has the best looking solutions for you, but you haven't really explained your scenario too well, why are you repeating the same image and making it scrollable? That doesn't sound like valid functionality for anything.  Are you trying to scale a background image or something? IF so, what's with the scroll bar???

Anyways here you go:
http://wowslider.com/rq/ajax-image-scroller/

Comment: It's like a table, each cell is a image and the row is scrollable (i.e., it doesn't break when it hit's the right side of the screen).

Comment: I don't think you want a horizontal scroll bar on your site, what do you mean when it hits the right side... and based on what your describing, any of the examples in the link I gave you have arrows that allow for image scrolling.  If all you're trying to do is get an image to repeat across the width of the page: create a div of 100% width and set it's background in css to the image and set it to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Garry's answer is good. If you just want regular scrollbars, however, wrap the dynamic area (into which you will be loading your images) with a div (or canvas, probably works the same way), and add a class to it. Then you can target all of the images with CSS and have them float, which will line them up, regardless of how many you load dynamically. (Just don't forget to put a width on the container.)

It would look something like this (short-hand, but you get the idea):

```
div.image-container {
width: 400px;
overflow: scroll;
}

div.image-loader img {
float: left;
}

<div class="image-loader">
  <img/>
  <img/>
</div>
```